# How many ways can b balls be distributed in c containers where each container has n labeled slots?

Tags: combinatorics

If each container has n unlabeled slots, the problem is same as the one "How many ways can b balls be distributed in c containers with no more than n balls in any given container?" The answer is known as

$$
N(b,c,n)=∑_{i}(−1)^{i}{c\choose i}{b+c−1−i(n+1)\choose c−1}.
$$

When each container has n labeled slots, what is the total number of distributed ways?

(As user84413 said, the total number of choices is $ {nc\choose b} $)

I need to rephrase my question (sorry about this). My question is: what is the probability that no container has n balls?

Peng

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: In my question, each container has n labeled slots, which means there are n choices if we just put one ball to a container. If the container is unlabeled, only one choice to put a ball to a container.

Comment: Are all the balls identical?

Comment: Yes, all balls are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 
you are choosing b slots out of the nc possible slots in which to put the balls,
the total number of distributions is $\binom {nc}{b}$.

To find the probability that no container contains n balls, we can let 
$A_i$ be the distributions in which container i receives n balls, for $1\le i \le c$.  Using Inclusion-Exclusion to find $|\overline {A_{1}}\cap \cdots \cap \overline {A_{c}}|$ gives

P(no container has n balls) = $\displaystyle{ \frac{\sum_ {i=0}^{c} (-1)^{i}\binom{c}{i}\binom{n(c-i)}{b-in}}{\binom{nc}{b}}}$.

Comment: I need to rephrase my question (sorry about this). My question is: what is the probability that no container has n balls?

Comment: Thanks. The result is right except that the upper range for i should be floor(c/n).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I concede that my answer may not be completely correct.  If you take b=4, c=3, and n=2, though, I believe my formula gives the correct answer of 0, while summing from 0 to floor(3/2)=1 does not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I make a typo, and the upper bound for i is floor(b/n).

Comment: That makes sense. (I believe the two formulas are equivalent, if you define $\binom {k}{l}=0$ if $l<0$.)